# Ошибка при добавлении в БД Mysql Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

При добавлении данных в бд вылетает ошибка отсутсвует столбей Image Price Title(Это свойства которые нужны для вывода данных их в этой таблице нет) Как обойти свойства(Чтобы они не добавлялись в бд ,но чтобы их было видно для вывода данных в Listview)

Основной класс Chek

```
    public partial class Chek
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
 
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
  
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
      
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Модифицированный класс  Chek с свойствами гетерами

```
public partial class Cheks
    {
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public Uri ImagePreview1
        {
            get
            {
                var imageName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + (Image ?? "");
                return System.IO.File.Exists(imageName) ? new Uri(imageName) : null;
            }
        }

        public string Pricey
        {
            get
            {
                return Price + " руб";
            }
        }


        public string Quantityy
        {
            get
            {
                return "Кол-во :" + Quantity + " шт";
            }
        }

       public int Quantity { get; private set; }
    }
```

код добавления

```
 private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (pos_productContext db = new pos_productContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    Chek chek = null;
                    if (CurretSale.Id != 0)
                        chek = db.Cheks.Find(CurretSale.Id);
                    else
                        chek = new Chek();
                    if (chek != null)
                    {
                      
                        chek.Quantity = CurretSale.Quantity;
                        chek.ProductId = CurrentProduct.Id;
                        db.Cheks.AddRange(chek);

                        if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                        {
                            DialogResult = true;
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                   // MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Добавляю я те поля которые имеются в базе ,но почему свойства лезут как столбцы ?? Я для этого создал отдельный класс но что то не так работает

Comment: Ок сейчас поменяю

Answer (score 0):

В классе контекста базы данных пишешь, чтобы EF игнорировал свойство:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Класс>().Ignore(u=>u.Свойство);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо.Я так и сделал но как мне теперь выводить таблицу ,эти свойства?

Comment: Мне эти свойства нужны для отображениz связанных[ данных  и таблицы Chek .При добавлении эти свойства мешают

Comment: То есть ты хочешь добавлять в базу данных Image? Но хочешь, чтобы Image не вытягивался из БД при запросе?

Comment: Я хочу добавить в таблицу Chek  то что есть в таблице Chek это id Product_Id Quantity.Но Когда я добавляю эти данные ,у меня не добавляются данные ,ссылаясь на свойства которые я обьявил в классе Chek их в бд нет.Эти свойства мне нужны только для оторажения данных ,их в бд я не вставляю

Comment: Откуда тогда Image берётся? Из локальной папки, верно?

Comment: да из текущего директория

Comment: Тут дело в том что Image Price Title это поля из таблицы продукт

Comment: Окей, кажется я понял, где собака зарыта. Ты пытаешься создать промежуточный объект с новыми свойствами, которых нет в БД. Не понимаю, как работает твой промежуточный объект, но это должно выглядеть так: промежуточный объект = данные из БД + данные не из БД (например Image). Потом ты промежуточные объекты отображаешь там, где тебе надо. И в конце концов, ты создал частичный класс Check с модификатором partial. Это значит, чтобы к имеющемуся классу, который относится к БД добавил свойство Image. И этот класс, состоящий из двух частей, ты пытаешься добавить в БД. Поэтому он ругается на Image.

Comment: Читай про Data Transfer Object. Я думаю, это то, что тебе нужно.

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Откуда у тебя должны браться данные для свойств Titile и Price в частичном классе Check?

Comment: Так то из класса Product ,потому что это связанные данные

Comment: public string Titles
        {
            get
            {
                return Product?.Title;
            }
        }

Comment: попробывал так вытаскивать данные из продукта дело в том что в таблице Chek есть только Product_ID а мне надо наименование цену и фото вытащить

Comment: Все проблему решил спасибо за ваши подсказки